# Select blocks when trying to read activity from file descriptors

Tags: c, sockets, select, block

I am trying to create a server that accepts multiple clients. Here is a part of my code. My server needs to `listen` to two `ports`. The `sockets` that achieve this are `fd_serv` and `fd_comm`.

Using `select` and `nonblock` file descriptors, unfortunately does not give me the desired output. The problems are that `select` `accepts` the first `client` and then blocks, and doesn't read messages from other `clients`.

Also for some reason if I don't use the `usleep(100000)` command, my program succeeds accepting but doesn't go on.

Any help appreciated.

```
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(fd_serv, &set);
FD_SET(fd_comm, &set); 
while (1)
    {
    if (select (max_fd + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror ("select");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < max_fd + 1; i++)
    {
        usleep(100000);
        if (FD_ISSET (i, &set))
        {
            if (i == fd_serv)       //Connection request on original socket.
            {
                new_serv = accept (fd_serv, (struct sockaddr *) &client_serv_addr, &sin_len_serv);
                if (new_serv < 0){ perror ("accept"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
                fd_set_blocking(new_serv, 0);
                FD_SET(new_serv, &set);
                max_fd = max(max_fd, new_serv);
            }
            else if (i == fd_comm)  //Connection request on original socket.
            {
                new_comm = accept (fd_comm, (struct sockaddr *) &client_comm_addr, &sin_len_comm);
                if (new_comm < 0){ perror ("accept"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
                fd_set_blocking(new_comm, 0);
                FD_SET (new_comm, &set);
                max_fd = max(max_fd, new_comm);
            }
            else if (i == new_comm) //Activity on already connected socket
            {
                if (read_command(fd_comm, i, start_time) == 1)
                {
                    close(i);
                    FD_CLR(i, &set);
                    return SHUTDOWN;
                }
            }
            else if (i == new_serv) //Activity on already connected socket
            {
                read_service(i);
                close(i);
                FD_CLR(i, &set);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [Ask], and [MCVE].  Hard to debug code we can't compile, particularly hard when we don't have access to some of the important bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(fd_serv, &set);
FD_SET(fd_comm, &set); 
while (1) 
{
   [...]
```

You are only setting up your `fd_set` once, but your `fd_set` will be modified by the `select()` call, so you need to set it up once per iteration of your loop.  Try this instead:

```
while (1) 
{
   FD_ZERO(&set);
   FD_SET(fd_serv, &set);
   FD_SET(fd_comm, &set); 
   const int max_fd = (fd_serve > fd_comm) ? fd_serve : fd_comm;
   [...]
```

... after the `select()` call, the only `select()`-related thing you should be calling is `FD_ISSET()`.  All the other stuff is pointless, since your additional `FD_SET()` and `FD_CLR()` calls are modifying an `fd_set` that you're just going to wipe clean with the `FD_ZERO()` call at the beginning of the next while-loop iteration.

Also, as a side note:  that `usleep(10000)` call should go away -- if you're calling `select()` correctly, sleeping for arbitrary time periods outside of `select()` is neither necessary nor desirable.